# char array in MIPS

Tags: mips

How would I create a char array and access those chars in MIPS? Im doing a project and part of it is to do this. I understand how to with integers and cant find any reference online on how to deal with just chars, specifically im trying to port...

```
static char   hexdigits[16] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

Heres my failed attempt:

```
hexarray: .word '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F' #declare memory space for our hex array
```

EDIT: if someone could provide an example how to print out one of these items it would be very helpful (you can modify the code i have to whatever you wish). as I im just getting a memory address error.

Comment: Maybe turn hexarray to a string using .asciiz instead of .word '0123456789ABCDEF' Then you could loop using lb and comparing their ascii values or whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: I am just trying to read an value hexarray[i] given a certain i (its in a loop)

Comment: Yeah, if you aren't forced to use .word, then using an .asciiz string makes most sense to me. And you could get the value using lb.

Comment: I'm taking an Assembly course at the moment too, so I'm not too sure. You may need to use la (load address) and then lb (load byte), but I remember doing it without using load address before.

Answer (score 14):

```
static char   hexdigits[16] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

Can be translated into:

```
.data
hexdigits: .byte '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'
```

Or

```
.data
hexdigits: .ascii "0123456789ABCDEF"
```

We can access the elements using

```
la    $t0, hexdigits
lb    $t1, 0($t0)        # $t1 = hexdigits[0]
lb    $t2, 1($t0)        # $t2 = hexdigits[1]
```

You can print the element using a system call (if your simulator support it. Most do)

```
la    $t0, hexdigits          # address of the first element
lb    $a0, 10($t0)            # hexdigits[10] (which is 'A')
li    $v0, 11                 # I will assume syscall 11 is printchar (most simulators support it)
syscall                       # issue a system call
```