# How can I access the individual elements of an array in a loop?

Tags: assembly, mips

I need to print the cells of an array, I have an array which contains the word "HELLO_WORLD", I manage to print an index by its own but I can't manage to print all the cells one by one, here is the code :

```
loop:
la    $t0, hexdigits          # address of the first element
lb    $a0, 5($t0)            # hexdigits[10] (which is 'A')
li    $v0, 11 #system call service
syscall
addi $a0, $a0, 2
li    $v0, 11                 # I will assume syscall 11 is printchar (most simulators support it)
syscall                       # issue a system call
j end
```

Is there anyway to use the instruction lb $a0, $s0($t0) with a register that I can increment anytime I want? and not just a number?

Comment: possible duplicate of [char array in MIPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021039/char-array-in-mips)

Comment: I saw the website and it helped a little, but now I am stuck in printing the cells one by one, I have updated the question, I hope you see it.

Comment: Thank you for updating the question, I updated the title to be more in line with the actual question now.  This is not a duplicate of the question I posted, so I will retract my vote.

Comment: will just incrementing $t0 (in a loop) and using a 0 offset in the lb instruction do the trick?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To access any individual element of `array`, you can use it as:

```
la $t3, array         # put address of array into $t3
```

---

If array is a byte array, like:

```
array:   .byte    'H','E','L','L','O'
```

to access the i<sup>th</sup> element:

```
lb $a0, i($t3)        # this load the byte at address that is (i+$t3)
```

because each element is of 1 byte, so to access i<sup>th</sup> byte, access the address that is `i` offset to address of `array`.

You can also access it as:

```
addi $t1,$t3,i
lb $a0,0($t1)
```

---

If array is a word array, like:

```
array:   .word    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

to access the i<sup>th</sup> element:

```
lw $a0, j($t3)        #j=4*i, you will have to write j manually
```

because each element if of 4 byte and to access i<sup>th</sup> element, you will have to move `i*4` byte from the starting address of `array`.

There are also some other ways of accessing it:

```
li $t2, i            # put the index in $t2
add $t2, $t2, $t2    # double the index
add $t2, $t2, $t2    # double the index again (now 4x)
add $t1, $t3, $t2    # get address of ith location
lw $a0, 0($t1)
```

---

Example1:

```
.data
array:  .byte 'H','E','L','L','O','_','W','O','R','L','D'
string: .asciiz "HELLO_WORLD"
size:   .word   11
array1: .word   1,2,3,4,0,6,7,8,9

.text
.globl main
main:
    li $v0, 11

    la $a2,array

    lb $a0,0($a2)        #access 1st element of array or array[0]
    syscall
    lb $a0,1($a2)        #access 2nd element of byte array or array[1]
    syscall
    lb $a0,2($a2)        #access 3rd element of byte array or array[2]
    syscall
    lb $a0,10($a2)       #access 11th element of byte array or array[10]
    syscall
    li $a0,10
    syscall
    syscall
    li $v0,1
    la $a3,array1
    lw $a0,0($a3)        #access 1st element of word array or array[0]
    syscall
    lw $a0,4($a3)        #access 2nd element of word array or array[1]
    syscall
    lw $a0,8($a3)        #access 3rd element of word array or array[2]
    syscall
    lw $a0,12($a3)       #access 4th element of word array or array[3]
    syscall
    jr $ra
```

Example:
Prints the byte array:

```
    li $v0, 11
    la $a2,array
    lw $t0,size
loop1:                         #print array
    lb $a0, 0($a2)             #load byte at address stored in $a2
    syscall
    add $t0,$t0,-1
    add $a2,$a2,1              #go to the next byte, since it is a byte array it will go to the address of next element
#to use it for printing word array instead of adding 1 add 4
    bgtz $t0, loop1
```

Comment: This actually works, the problem i had was doing the offset, thank you for the solution and the great explanation.

Comment: `slli add $t3, $t2, 2` to scale by 4 in one instruction.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my best attempt at a solution for what you are after.

```
.data
mystring: .asciiz "HELLO_WORLD"    # zero-terminated string

.text
la $t0, mystring  # Load the array
li $t1, 0         # Create the loop counter
li $v0, 11        # Syscall code for print character       

loop:

    add $t2, $t0, $t1    # Load the address for the element at the current index
    lb $a0, 0($t2)       # Load the value of the array at the current index into $a0
                         # (For printing)

    beqz $a0, exit       # If the value at the current index is null, you have 
                         # reached the end of the string, so exit out

    syscall              # Print the character in $a0 (Syscall code in $v0: 11)

    addi $t1, $t1, 1     # Increment the counter

    j loop               # Jump to the beginning of the loop    

exit: # Should be reached once you have hit the end of the string
```

**Disclaimer:** I do not know MIPS assembly, I tried to pick up as much as I could to research your question.  I could only test this program in an online emulator that did not support printing to the screen (syscall).  **Do not just blindly paste this code and respond with "Nope, doesn't work"**.  If there are any problems please try to be specific and I'll try to figure out the issue.

---

Editor's notes: looks ok to me, after fixing `.asciiz` to make sure there's a zero terminator even if other non-zero data is placed right after it in the .data section.

`v0=11` / `syscall` leaves `$v0` unmodified, so the `li $v0, 11` can be hoisted out of the loop.  Some system calls put a return value in `$v0`, but this one doesn't.  ([MARS syscall docs](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html))

Instead of a counter starting at 0, we could directly increment the `$t1` pointer.

To make this more efficient, we could "rotate" the loop so there was a `bnez $a0, loop` at the bottom (no `j` needed), probably by peeling the first iteration: load and check a char before the loop, then fall into the loop with printing as the first thing.  Then increment, load and check the next char and either fall out of the loop or jump to the top to print it, too.

Answer (score 0):

I am beginner at Mips assebly , but I from what I 've learned i think you can do it as such:
Every element of the array is been given  4bytes (it maybe be actually less but no other element it's going to store anything on these 4 bytes, these are dedicated to only one element).
So, between the adresses of two elements k,k+1, there is  a distance of 4bytes(always).
As mentioned above, if you want to reach the i-th element you need to add to the adress of the first (A[0]) the offset distance which is 4*i.
One way to create this offset distance other than `mul` instruction is :

```
sll $t1, $t0, 2
```

this actually means "shift left the value in register $t0 , 2 bits (fill the rest with 0's) and store the result in register $t1 .  But you can easily notice , that if you shift left and fill with zero , for every shift you actually multiply the current value by 2 ( please note that we use this if we know that we have enough space, to avoid overfloating)

So if for instance in $t0, you had 0001 in $t1 you will gain 0100
So basically : you need

```
sll $t1, $t0, 2 # [t1]=4i
lb $a0, t1($t0)  # a0 = A[i]
```

*if you are a more experienced Mips programmer, and I am wrong , edit my post or comment to make sure everyone of us gets better

Comment: `t1($t0)` is not a valid MIPS addressing mode; it only has `constant(register)` for a 16-bit sign-extended immediate constant.  That's why you normally do pointer increments (by 4) instead of using sll/add to redo indexing each iteration.  (For word elements.  Just add for 1-byte elements like the question's char array)  But yes, left-shift by `n` = multiply by `2^n`, and you should always use shifts instead of actual `mul` or `mult` for known powers of 2.